# Django: custom content in admin form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-widget

For one of my models, I want to show extra content in the change_form. Basically, my model looks like this:

```
class News(models.Model):
    ...

class NewsFromSource(models.Model):
    news                    = models.ForeignKey(News)
    ...
```

I want to add a 'search' button that, when clicked, triggers a web service request to an external news source, pulls down the available content, and lists all the news pieces contained. The user can then select one of the pieces to "attach" to the News currently edited in the admin interface (i.e. create a new NewsFromSource based on the content downloaded through the web service).

I am done with the web service. What is the best approach to implementing the search-button, list display for the results (I have a view and template that work, need to get those into the form somehow) and the saving part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing is the following:

1)

I created a view for fetching search results, which boils down to this:

```
#/myproject/admin/views.py
@never_cache
def news_search(request):

    #...query web service
    if 'q' in request.POST:
        search_term = request.POST['q']
    else:
        search_term = ''

    news = NewsSearch()
    news.search(search_term)

    return render_to_response(  'news_search_results.html', 
                            {   'q':            search_term,
                                'news':     news.result_list,
                                'page':         page,
                                'page_left':    news.page_left, 
                                'page_right':   news.page_right}
                                )
```

2) I mapped the view:

```
#/myapp/urls.py
...
url(r'^myapp/news/search/$', views.news_search),
```

3) I extended change_form.html for the news model with the following code:

```
#/myproject/templates/admin/myapp/news/change_form.html
    {% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
    {% block after_field_sets %}
    ...
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="q" id="news-search-term">
    <div id="news-search-results"></div>
   ...
    function submitSearchForm() {
    $.post("/myapp/news/search/",
        {   'q': $('#news-search-term').val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val() },
        function(data){
            $('#news-search-results').html(data);
        } 
    );
}
    {{ block.super }}
    {% endblock %}
```

4) I created an html template for displaying the results (news_search_results.html, see 1)

So basically I am sending an AJAX request from the admin page to a custom view to retrieve results from the webservice which then are displayed in a div.

Each element in the results list has a button that sends another request that stores the element with the news id as a ForeignKey.

I have no idea whether this is particularly against Django principles. But it seems to work alright.

Suggestions on doing this in a more "Djangonian" way are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

1. We'll assume you have **a related News model**. Add that field to **raw_id_fields** of the modeladmin we're going to hack, then:
2. **Overload the [change_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) template for this model**, extend `admin/change_form.html` in `admin/yourapp/yourmodel/change_form.html`
3. **Add javascript in that template** to:

   1. Hide the input and magnifier icon from the news raw id field form raw, you can do that in css too
   2. Add something like a span with a button style in that form row that will open a popup when it is clicked
   3. The popup it should open should be your working view/template with a form to select the news
   4. When the user selects a news, the popup should do an ajax post request to get the news id, and close itself
   5. the value is set to the raw id field input that is hidden, this is pretty tough but fear not someone (disclamer: I) published [an article with the whole technical details](http://oldblog.yourlabs.org/blog/2010/05/12/howto-javascript-popup-form-returning-value-select-django-admin-foreign-keys/), also found [another one but I didn't test it](http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/replicating-djangos-admin/)

It's going to be quite some work. Patience and perseverance will be your best qualities for this mission B)

Comment: Sorry i just figured out the popup will not be able to "return" json very easily so I changed my advice

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, it turns out i had a hack in my hosts file ... updated the link

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely try this and let you know how it worked out.The hiding the magnifier icon bit seems a bit hackish. Is there no other way?

Comment: Actually I think that is not what I am looking for. I want to start from the News item, search existing news on the internet, and then create a new NewsSource item with ForeignKey News.

The approach you described works the other way round, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Well at the point of 3.4. the user selects a news, so it's time to save it. Additionally, the popup should return the id of the news at point 3.5. so everything's in order to close the deal B) but it would be better for you to find an easier solution - a js popover would make it easier.